# Prepare the data for PostgreSQL COPY

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, sqlbulkcopy

I have a list of objects which are scrapped content from a HTML pages and some of the values are HTML code which has special characters like quote and single quote `( like <a href="http://.."> )` and that needed to be escaped while preparing the CSV string but the inserted values are escaped so the HTML code is corrupted.

My code :

```
import csv
import subprocess

insert_process = subprocess.Popen([
        'psql', 'dbname', '-U', 'user',
        '-c', '\COPY products(name,description,image) FROM STDIN',
        '--set=ON_ERROR_STOP=true'
        ], stdin=subprocess.PIPE


/****
Looping on the object and convert them to CSV raw with 'serialize_post_to_out_stream' function and append them to the stdin
*****/



# function to remove the new line and tab chars
def clean_vars(var):
    return var.replace('\t', '').replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '')

# function to convert the product object to csv raw
def serialize_post_to_out_stream(product, out):
    writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter="\t",quotechar='\'', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow([product.name,clean_vars(product.description),product.image])

# Closing the process to execute the COPY 
insert_process.stdin.close()
```

Everything is working fine but the 'description' is corrupted HTML code like :

```
'<li id="description" class="level-1">(DX-format): 5°20''</li>      </li>'
```

There are some unwanted chars like the single quote in the beginning and the end of the value and if I removed :

```
quotechar='\''
```

Then every quote will be escaped with another quote.
How to escape them for the CSV but inserting them cleaned in the DB.

Comment: First you want to add a `FORMAT CSV` option to the `\copy` invocation because that's not the default, and the appropriate `QUOTE` option matching your csv generator. Don't manually remove newlines or tabs, they're supported by CSV with proper quoting when conforming to RFC 4180.